# Parsing a command language using Boost Spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, scripting, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am building a parser for a command language that I've pieced together from various samples. I've read the Boost Spirit Qi and Lex docs, and I think I understand the basics, but from what I've read, I should avoid attributes and use utree. What docs I've found on utree basically suck. Given the code below, I have the following questions:

1. How do I annotate the parser to create an AST using utree?
2. How do I walk the utree after it is built, to discover what was parsed? e.g. for token-only commands, such as SET DEBUG ON, as well as commands with values, such as LOAD "file.ext" or SET DRIVE C:
3. I want to add a comment character, "!". So, how can I ignore everything after that - except when it occurs in a quoted string?
4. Why doesn't my error handler get called when I give it invalid input?
5. How can I make the command tokens case insensitive, but not change the contents of a quoted string?

   ```
   #include <Windows.h>
   #include <conio.h>
   #include <string>
   #include <vector>
   #include <iostream>

   #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG

   #include <boost\spirit\include\qi.hpp>
   #include <boost\spirit\include\phoenix.hpp>
   #include <boost\spirit\include\lex.hpp>
   #include <boost\spirit\include\lex_lexertl.hpp>

   using namespace std;
   using namespace boost::spirit;
   using boost::spirit::utree;

   //
   // Tokens used by the command grammar
   //

   template <typename Lexer>
   struct command_tokens : lex::lexer <Lexer>
       {
       command_tokens () :

           //
           // Verbs, with abbreviation (just enough characters to make each unique)
           //

           boot        ("B(O(O(T)?)?)?"),
           exit        ("E(X(I(T)?)?)?"),
           help        ("H(E(L(P)?)?)?"),
           dash_help   ("-H(E(L(P)?)?)?"),
           slash_help  ("\\/H(E(L(P)?)?)?"),
           load        ("L(O(A(D)?)?)?"),
           quit        ("Q(U(I(T)?)?)?"),
           set         ("SE(T)?"),
           show        ("SH(O(W)?)?"),

           //
           // Nouns, with abbreviation (the minimum number of characters is usually 3, but may be more to ensure uniqueness)
           //

           debug       ("DEB(U(G)?)?"),
           drive       ("DRI(V(E)?)?"),
           trace       ("TRA(C(E)?)?"),

           //
           // Qualifiers
           //

           on          ("ON"),
           off         ("OFF"),

           //
           // Tokens to pass back to the grammar
           //

           quoted_string   ("...")

           {
           using namespace boost::spirit::lex;

           //
           // Associate the tokens with the lexer
           //

           this->self 
               = boot
               | exit
               | help
               | dash_help
               | slash_help
               | load
               | quit
               | set
               | show
               | debug
               | drive
               | trace
               | off
               | on
               | quoted_string
               ;

           //
           // Define whitespace to ignore: space, tab, newline
           //

           this->self ("WS")
               = lex::token_def <> ("[ \\t\\n]+")
               ;
           }

       lex::token_def <>   boot;
       lex::token_def <>   dash_help;
       lex::token_def <>   debug;
       lex::token_def <string> drive;
       lex::token_def <>   exit;
       lex::token_def <>   help;
       lex::token_def <>   load;
       lex::token_def <>   off;
       lex::token_def <>   on;
       lex::token_def <>   quit;
       lex::token_def <string> quoted_string;
       lex::token_def <>   set;
       lex::token_def <>   show;
       lex::token_def <>   slash_help;
       lex::token_def <>   trace;
       };

   //
   // Display parse error
   //

   struct error_handler_
       {
       template <typename, typename, typename>
       struct result
           {
           typedef void type;
           };

       template <typename Iterator>
       void operator ()
           (
           qi::info const& What,
           Iterator        Err_pos,
           Iterator        Last
           ) const

           {
           cout << "Error! Expecting "
               << What
               << " here: \""
               << string (Err_pos, Last)
               << "\""
               << endl;
           }
       };

   boost::phoenix::function <error_handler_> const error_handler = error_handler_ ();

   //
   // Grammar describing the valid commands
   //

   template <typename Iterator, typename Lexer>
   struct command_grammar : qi::grammar <Iterator>
       {
       template <typename Lexer>
       command_grammar (command_tokens <Lexer> const& Tok) :
           command_grammar::base_type (start)
           {
           using qi::on_error;
           using qi::fail;
           using qi::char_;

           start
               = +commands;

           commands
               = (
                 boot_command
               | exit_command
               | help_command
               | load_command
               | set_command
               | show_command
               );

           boot_command
               = Tok.boot;

           exit_command
               = Tok.exit
               | Tok.quit;

           help_command
               = Tok.help
               | Tok.dash_help
               | Tok.slash_help;

           load_command
               = Tok.load >> Tok.quoted_string;

           set_command
               = Tok.set;

           show_command
               = Tok.show;

           set_property
               = debug_property
               | drive_property
               | trace_property;

           debug_property
               = Tok.debug >> on_off;

          drive_property
               = Tok.drive >> char_ ("A-Z") >> char_ (":");

           trace_property
               = Tok.trace >> on_off;

           on_off
               = Tok.on
               | Tok.off;

           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE (start);
           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE (commands);
           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE (boot_command);
           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE (exit_command);
           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE (help_command);
           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE (load_command);
           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE (quit_command);
           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE (set_command);
           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE (show_command);
           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE (set_property);
           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE (debug_property);
           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE (drive_property);
           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE (trace_property);
           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE (target_property);
           on_error <fail> (start, error_handler (_4, _3, _2));
           }

       qi::rule <Iterator> start;
       qi::rule <Iterator> commands;
       qi::rule <Iterator> boot_command;
       qi::rule <Iterator> exit_command;
       qi::rule <Iterator> help_command;
       qi::rule <Iterator> load_command;
       qi::rule <Iterator> quit_command;
       qi::rule <Iterator> set_command;
       qi::rule <Iterator> show_command;
       qi::rule <Iterator> set_property;
       qi::rule <Iterator> debug_property;
       qi::rule <Iterator, string ()>  drive_property;
       qi::rule <Iterator> target_property;
       qi::rule <Iterator> trace_property;
       qi::rule <Iterator> on_off;
       };

   int
   main
       (
       int     Argc,
       PCHAR   Argv
       )
   {
       typedef std::string::iterator                       base_iterator_type;
       typedef lex::lexertl::token <base_iterator_type>    token_type;
       typedef lex::lexertl::lexer <token_type>            lexer_type;
       typedef command_tokens <lexer_type>                 command_tokens;
       typedef command_tokens::iterator_type               iterator_type;
       typedef command_grammar <iterator_type, command_tokens::lexer_def>  command_grammar;

       command_tokens      tokens;
       command_grammar     commands (tokens);
       string              input = "SET DRIVE C:";
       string::iterator    it = input.begin ();
       iterator_type       iter = tokens.begin (it, input.end ());
       iterator_type       end = tokens.end ();
       string              ws ("WS");

       bool                result = lex::tokenize_and_phrase_parse (it, input.end (), tokens, commands, qi::in_state (ws) [tokens.self]);

       if (result)
           {
           cout << "Parse succeeded" << endl;
           }
       else
           {
           string  rest (it, input.end ());
           cout << "Parse failed" << endl;
           cout << "Stopped at " << rest << endl;
           }

       return 0;
   }                           // End of main
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to side-step the majority of your code, for the simple reasons that experience tells me that `Lex` and `utree` are generally not what you want to use.

What you do want is define an AST to represent your command language and then come up with a grammar to build it.

#### AST

```
namespace Ast {
    struct NoValue {
        bool operator==(NoValue const &) const { return true; }
    };
    template <typename Tag> struct GenericCommand {};

    namespace tag {
        struct boot;
        struct help;
        struct load;
        struct exit;
        struct set;
        struct show;
    };

    template <> struct GenericCommand<tag::load> { std::string name; };

    template <> struct GenericCommand<tag::set> {
        std::string property;
        boost::variant<NoValue, std::string, bool> value; // optional
    };

    using BootCmd = GenericCommand<tag::boot>;
    using HelpCmd = GenericCommand<tag::help>;
    using ExitCmd = GenericCommand<tag::exit>;
    using ShowCmd = GenericCommand<tag::show>;
    using LoadCmd = GenericCommand<tag::load>;
    using SetCmd  = GenericCommand<tag::set>;

    using Command = boost::variant<BootCmd, HelpCmd, ExitCmd, ShowCmd, LoadCmd, SetCmd>;
    using Commands = std::list<Command>;
}
```

The full code only adds debug output helpers. And here's the full Fusion Adaption:

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_TPL_STRUCT((Tag), (Ast::GenericCommand) (Tag), )
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::LoadCmd, name)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::SetCmd, property, value)
```

#### Grammar

Here I make some choices:

- let's make things white-space and case insensitive, allowing line-separated commands: (see also [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965))

  ```
  start = skip(blank) [lazy_command % eol];
  ```
- let's use [Nabialek Trick](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/nabialek-trick/) to associate commands with prefixes. I used a very simple snippet of code to generate the unique prefixes:

  ```
  std::set<std::string> const verbs { "boot", "exit", "help", "-help", "/help", "load", "quit", "set", "show", };
  for (auto const full : verbs)
      for (auto partial=full; partial.length(); partial.resize(partial.size()-1)) {
          auto n = std::distance(verbs.lower_bound(partial), verbs.upper_bound(full));
          if (n < 2) std::cout << "(\"" << partial << "\", &" << full << "_command)\n";
      }
  ```
- you could do the same for properties, but I thought the current setup is simpler:

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct command_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, Ast::Commands()> {
    command_grammar() : command_grammar::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        start = skip(blank) [lazy_command % eol];

        // nabialek trick
        lazy_command = no_case [ commands [ _a = _1 ] > lazy(*_a) [ _val = _1 ] ];

        on_off.add("on", true)("off", false);

        commands.add
            ("-help", &help_command) ("-hel", &help_command) ("-he", &help_command) ("-h", &help_command)
            ("/help", &help_command) ("/hel", &help_command) ("/he", &help_command) ("/h", &help_command)
            ("help", &help_command) ("hel", &help_command) ("he", &help_command) ("h", &help_command)
            ("boot", &boot_command) ("boo", &boot_command) ("bo", &boot_command) ("b", &boot_command)
            ("exit", &exit_command) ("exi", &exit_command) ("ex", &exit_command) ("e", &exit_command)
            ("quit", &exit_command) ("qui", &exit_command) ("qu", &exit_command) ("q", &exit_command)
            ("load", &load_command) ("loa", &load_command) ("lo", &load_command) ("l", &load_command)
            ("set", &set_command) ("se", &set_command)
            ("show", &show_command) ("sho", &show_command) ("sh", &show_command);

        quoted_string = '"' >> +~char_('"') >> '"';

        // nullary commands
        boot_command_ = eps;
        exit_command_ = eps;
        help_command_ = eps;
        show_command_ = eps;

        // non-nullary commands
        load_command_ = quoted_string;
        drive_        = char_("A-Z") >> ':';
        set_command_  = no_case[lit("drive")|"driv"|"dri"|"dr"] >> attr("DRIVE") >> drive_
                | no_case[ (lit("debug")|"debu"|"deb"|"de")     >> attr("DEBUG") >> on_off ]
                | no_case[ (lit("trace")|"trac"|"tra"|"tr"|"t") >> attr("TRACE") >> on_off ]
                ;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                (start)(lazy_command)
                (boot_command) (exit_command) (help_command) (show_command) (set_command) (load_command)
                (boot_command_)(exit_command_)(help_command_)(show_command_)(set_command_)(load_command_)
                (quoted_string)(drive_)
            )

        on_error<fail>(start, error_handler_(_4, _3, _2));
        on_error<fail>(lazy_command, error_handler_(_4, _3, _2));
        boot_command = boot_command_;
        exit_command = exit_command_;
        help_command = help_command_;
        load_command = load_command_;
        exit_command = exit_command_;
        set_command  = set_command_;
        show_command = show_command_;
    }

  private:
    struct error_handler_t {
        template <typename...> struct result { typedef void type; };

        void operator()(qi::info const &What, Iterator Err_pos, Iterator Last) const {
            std::cout << "Error! Expecting " << What << " here: \"" << std::string(Err_pos, Last) << "\"" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    boost::phoenix::function<error_handler_t> const error_handler_ = error_handler_t {};

    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Commands()> start;

    using Skipper = qi::blank_type;
    using CommandRule  = qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Command(), Skipper>;

    qi::symbols<char, bool> on_off;
    qi::symbols<char, CommandRule const*> commands;

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> drive_property, quoted_string, drive_;

    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Command(), Skipper, qi::locals<CommandRule const*> > lazy_command;
    CommandRule boot_command, exit_command, help_command, load_command, set_command, show_command;

    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::BootCmd(), Skipper> boot_command_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::ExitCmd(), Skipper> exit_command_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::HelpCmd(), Skipper> help_command_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::LoadCmd(), Skipper> load_command_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::SetCmd(),  Skipper> set_command_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::ShowCmd(), Skipper> show_command_;
};
```

### Test Cases

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ec80a0618ba2560)</kbd>**

```
int main() {
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    command_grammar<It> const commands;

    for (std::string const input : {
            "help",
            "set drive C:",
            "SET DRIVE C:",
            "loAD \"XYZ\"",
            "load \"anything \nat all\"",
            // multiline
            "load \"ABC\"\nhelp\n-he\n/H\nsh\nse t off\nse debug ON\nb\nq"
            })
    {
        std::cout << "----- '" << input << "' -----\n";
        It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

        Ast::Commands parsed;
        bool result = parse(f, l, commands, parsed);

        if (result) {
            for (auto& cmd : parsed) {
                std::cout << "Parsed " << cmd << "\n";
            }
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
        }

        if (f != l) {
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed '" << std::string(f, l) << "'\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
----- 'help' -----
Parsed HELP ()
----- 'set drive C:' -----
Parsed SET (DRIVE C)
----- 'SET DRIVE C:' -----
Parsed SET (DRIVE C)
----- 'loAD "XYZ"' -----
Parsed LOAD (XYZ)
----- 'load "anything 
at all"' -----
Parsed LOAD (anything 
at all)
----- 'load "ABC"
help
-he
/H
sh
se t off
se debug ON
b
q' -----
Parsed LOAD (ABC)
Parsed HELP ()
Parsed HELP ()
Parsed HELP ()
Parsed SHOW ()
Parsed SET (TRACE 0)
Parsed SET (DEBUG 1)
Parsed BOOT ()
Parsed EXIT ()
```

### Full Listing

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ec80a0618ba2560)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace Ast {
    struct NoValue {
        bool operator==(NoValue const &) const { return true; }
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, NoValue) { return os; }
    };
    template <typename Tag> struct GenericCommand {};

    namespace tag {
        struct boot {};
        struct help {};
        struct load {};
        struct exit {};
        struct set {};
        struct show {};

        static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, boot) { return os << "BOOT"; }
        static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, help) { return os << "HELP"; }
        static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, load) { return os << "LOAD"; }
        static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, exit) { return os << "EXIT"; }
        static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, set ) { return os << "SET"; }
        static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, show) { return os << "SHOW"; }
    };

    template <> struct GenericCommand<tag::load> { std::string name; };

    template <> struct GenericCommand<tag::set> {
        std::string property;
        boost::variant<NoValue, std::string, bool> value; // optional
    };

    using BootCmd = GenericCommand<tag::boot>;
    using HelpCmd = GenericCommand<tag::help>;
    using ExitCmd = GenericCommand<tag::exit>;
    using ShowCmd = GenericCommand<tag::show>;
    using LoadCmd = GenericCommand<tag::load>;
    using SetCmd  = GenericCommand<tag::set>;

    using Command = boost::variant<BootCmd, HelpCmd, ExitCmd, ShowCmd, LoadCmd, SetCmd>;
    using Commands = std::list<Command>;

    template <typename Tag>
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Ast::GenericCommand<Tag> const& command) { 
        return os << Tag{} << " " << boost::fusion::as_vector(command);
    }
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_TPL_STRUCT((Tag), (Ast::GenericCommand) (Tag), )
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::LoadCmd, name)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::SetCmd, property, value)

template <typename Iterator>
struct command_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, Ast::Commands()> {
    command_grammar() : command_grammar::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        start = skip(blank) [lazy_command % eol];

        // nabialek trick
        lazy_command = no_case [ commands [ _a = _1 ] > lazy(*_a) [ _val = _1 ] ];

        on_off.add("on", true)("off", false);

        commands.add
            ("-help", &help_command) ("-hel", &help_command) ("-he", &help_command) ("-h", &help_command)
            ("/help", &help_command) ("/hel", &help_command) ("/he", &help_command) ("/h", &help_command)
            ("help", &help_command) ("hel", &help_command) ("he", &help_command) ("h", &help_command)
            ("boot", &boot_command) ("boo", &boot_command) ("bo", &boot_command) ("b", &boot_command)
            ("exit", &exit_command) ("exi", &exit_command) ("ex", &exit_command) ("e", &exit_command)
            ("quit", &exit_command) ("qui", &exit_command) ("qu", &exit_command) ("q", &exit_command)
            ("load", &load_command) ("loa", &load_command) ("lo", &load_command) ("l", &load_command)
            ("set", &set_command) ("se", &set_command)
            ("show", &show_command) ("sho", &show_command) ("sh", &show_command);

        quoted_string = '"' >> +~char_('"') >> '"';

        // nullary commands
        boot_command_ = eps;
        exit_command_ = eps;
        help_command_ = eps;
        show_command_ = eps;

        // non-nullary commands
        load_command_ = quoted_string;
        drive_        = char_("A-Z") >> ':';
        set_command_  = no_case[lit("drive")|"driv"|"dri"|"dr"] >> attr("DRIVE") >> drive_
                | no_case[ (lit("debug")|"debu"|"deb"|"de")     >> attr("DEBUG") >> on_off ]
                | no_case[ (lit("trace")|"trac"|"tra"|"tr"|"t") >> attr("TRACE") >> on_off ]
                ;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                (start)(lazy_command)
                (boot_command) (exit_command) (help_command) (show_command) (set_command) (load_command)
                (boot_command_)(exit_command_)(help_command_)(show_command_)(set_command_)(load_command_)
                (quoted_string)(drive_)
            )

        on_error<fail>(start, error_handler_(_4, _3, _2));
        on_error<fail>(lazy_command, error_handler_(_4, _3, _2));
        boot_command = boot_command_;
        exit_command = exit_command_;
        help_command = help_command_;
        load_command = load_command_;
        exit_command = exit_command_;
        set_command  = set_command_;
        show_command = show_command_;
    }

  private:
    struct error_handler_t {
        template <typename...> struct result { typedef void type; };

        void operator()(qi::info const &What, Iterator Err_pos, Iterator Last) const {
            std::cout << "Error! Expecting " << What << " here: \"" << std::string(Err_pos, Last) << "\"" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    boost::phoenix::function<error_handler_t> const error_handler_ = error_handler_t {};

    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Commands()> start;

    using Skipper = qi::blank_type;
    using CommandRule  = qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Command(), Skipper>;

    qi::symbols<char, bool> on_off;
    qi::symbols<char, CommandRule const*> commands;

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> drive_property, quoted_string, drive_;

    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Command(), Skipper, qi::locals<CommandRule const*> > lazy_command;
    CommandRule boot_command, exit_command, help_command, load_command, set_command, show_command;

    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::BootCmd(), Skipper> boot_command_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::ExitCmd(), Skipper> exit_command_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::HelpCmd(), Skipper> help_command_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::LoadCmd(), Skipper> load_command_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::SetCmd(),  Skipper> set_command_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::ShowCmd(), Skipper> show_command_;
};

int main() {
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    command_grammar<It> const commands;

    for (std::string const input : {
            "help",
            "set drive C:",
            "SET DRIVE C:",
            "loAD \"XYZ\"",
            "load \"anything \nat all\"",
            // multiline
            "load \"ABC\"\nhelp\n-he\n/H\nsh\nse t off\nse debug ON\nb\nq"
            })
    {
        std::cout << "----- '" << input << "' -----\n";
        It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

        Ast::Commands parsed;
        bool result = parse(f, l, commands, parsed);

        if (result) {
            for (auto& cmd : parsed) {
                std::cout << "Parsed " << cmd << "\n";
            }
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
        }

        if (f != l) {
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed '" << std::string(f, l) << "'\n";
        }
    }
}
```

### POST-SCRIPT

> **Q.** How do I annotate the parser to create an AST using utree?

- See above

> **Q.** How do I walk the utree after it is built, to discover what was parsed?

- See above, see also http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html

> **Q.** I want to add a comment character, "!". So, how can I ignore everything after that - except when it occurs in a quoted string?

- Simply make the `Skipper` type a rule that parses e.g.:

  ```
  qi::rule<Iterator> my_skipper;
  my_skipper = blank | '!' >> *(char_ - eol) >> (eol|eoi);
  ```

  Then use it instead of `skip(blank)` like `skip(my_skipper)`

> **Q.** Why doesn't my error handler get called when I give it invalid input?

- Because you didn't mark expectation points (`operator>` instead of `operator>>`). If you don't, a failure to match a sub-expression simply backtracks.

> **Q.** How can I make the command tokens case insensitive, but not change the contents of a quoted string?

- See above

Comment: Added a point-by-point answer to all the numbered questions as a POST-SCRIPT

Comment: This is absolutely AWESOME! I've been struggling with this for a few days. THANK YOU VERY MUCH! I can follow what you did, but I suspect that it would take me a long time to be able to create something like this.

Comment: @Brian don't sell yourself short :) Lex + utree complicate matters enough, so actually you did well (even with state switching lexer, kudos!). If you want to read about my prejudice about Lexers and utree, find my [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874410/c-boostspirit-parsing-embedded-languages/28874704#28874704)/[chats](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/20528838#20528838) on site. Or the Spirit maintainers for that matter. I think utree was never quite completed, and Spirit X3 doesn't even have a lexer mode anymore, AFAIK

Comment: which method would you recommend for processing the parsed data, adding a token_id attribute to each rule and processing them, or an action routine attached to a parse rule? I suspect the latter, but I don't know enough to evaluate them. In either case, how do I get the parameters (strings, such as filename) when looking at the token list or in the action routine?

Comment: Nah [semantic actions are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil). Just, forget about tokens. You have the AST now. Just use the same as is being used to print (see also my second POST-SCRIPT item). Exampe: https://wandbox.org/permlink/axbq87WGxAWnNiZh

Comment: Again, thank you very much for your efforts; I am in your debt. I have learned an enormous amount from you! All of the "behind the scenes" work done by Phoenix still isn't clear to me, but your example helps a great deal, and allows me to move forward. If you ever make it to the island of Kauai (in the state of Hawaii) let me know, I'll be happy to be your tour guide