# Boost spirit skip parser with at least one whitespace

Tags: boost, boost-spirit

In the grammar i'm implementing, there are elements separated by whitespace. With a skip parser, the spaces between the elements are skipped automatically, but this also allows *no* space, which is not what i want. Sure, i could explicitly write a grammar that includes these spaces, but it seems to me (with the complexity and flexibility offered by spirit) that there is a better way to do this. Is there?
Here is an example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>    

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        std::exit(1);
    }
    std::string str = argv[1];
    auto iter = str.begin();
    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(iter, str.end(), qi::char_ >> qi::char_, qi::blank);

    if (r && iter == str.end())
    {
        std::cout << "parse succeeded\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "parse failed. Remaining unparsed: " << std::string(iter, str.end()) << '\n';
    }
}
```

This allows `ab` as well as `a b`. I want only the latter to be allowed.

Related to this: How do the skip parsers work, exactly? One supplies something like qi::blank, is then the kleene star applied to form the skip parser? I would like to get some enlightenment here, maybe this also helps on solving this problem.

Additional information: My real parser looks something like this:

```
one   = char_("X") >> repeat(2)[omit[+blank] >> +alnum] >> qi::omit[+qi::blank] >> +alnum;
two   = char_("Y") >> repeat(3)[omit[+blank] >> +alnum];
three = char_("Z") >> repeat(4)[omit[+blank] >> +alnum] >> qi::omit[+qi::blank] >> +alnum;

main = one | two | three;
```

which makes the grammar quite noisy, which i would like to avoid.

Comment: The problem in your example is that `char_ ` matches any character (including white spaces). You can fix the example by using `~blank` or `~char_(' ')`. Your "real" parsers (with removed `omit[+blank]` things) do not have this problem and should run fine with `blank` skipper if you use `lexeme` properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, the grammar specs I usually see this kind of requirement in are (always?) RFCs. In 99% of cases there is no issue, consider e.g.:

```
 myrule = skip(space) [ uint_ >> uint_ ];
```

This already implicitly requires at least 1 whitespace character between the numbers, for the simple reason that there would be 1 number, otherwise. The same simplification occurs in surprisingly many cases (see e.g. the simplifications made around the ubiquitous WSP productions in this answer last week [Boost.Spirit qi value sequence vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52814609/boost-spirit-qi-value-sequence-vector/52825987)).

---

With that out of the way, skippers apply zero or more times, by definition, so no there is not a way to get what you want with an existing stateful directive like `skip()`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965 or the [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/s04.html#idx_id_10) - under `lexeme`, `[no_]skip` and `skip_flag::dont_postskip`).

---

Looking at your specific grammar, I'd do this:

```
bool r = qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, token >> token, qi::blank);
```

Here, you can add a negative lookahead assertion inside a lexeme to assert that "the end of the token was reached" - which in your parser would be mandated as `!qi::graph`:

```
    auto token = qi::copy(qi::lexeme [ qi::char_ >> !qi::graph ]);
```

See a demo:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff1d8587bb70058c)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    for (std::string const str : { "ab", " ab ", " a b ", "a b" }) {
        auto iter = str.begin(), end = str.end();

        auto token = qi::copy(qi::lexeme [ qi::char_ >> !qi::graph ]);

        bool r = qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, token >> token, qi::blank);

        std::cout << " --- " << std::quoted(str) << " --- ";
        if (r) {
            std::cout << "parse succeeded.";
        } else {
            std::cout << "parse failed.";
        }

        if (iter != end) {
            std::cout << " Remaining unparsed: " << std::string(iter, str.end());
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
 --- "ab" --- parse failed. Remaining unparsed: ab
 --- " ab " --- parse failed. Remaining unparsed:  ab 
 --- " a b " --- parse succeeded.
 --- "a b" --- parse succeeded.
```

### BONUS Review notes

My guidelines would be:

1. your skipper should be the grammar's responsibility. It's sad that all Qi samples lead people to believe you need to let the caller decide that
2. end-iterator checking does **not** equal error-checking. It's very possible to [parse things correctly without consuming all input](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73e15909ea5ec668). Which is why reporting the "remaining input" should not just happen in the case that parsing failed.
3. If trailing unparsed input **is** an error, [spell it out](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auxiliary/eoi.html):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e6f404617f4e721)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    for (std::string const str : { "ab", " ab ", " a b ", "a b happy trees are trailing" }) {
        auto iter = str.begin(), end = str.end();

        auto token = qi::copy(qi::lexeme [ qi::char_ >> !qi::graph ]);

        bool r = qi::parse(iter, end, qi::skip(qi::space) [ token >> token >> qi::eoi ]);

        std::cout << " --- " << std::quoted(str) << " --- ";
        if (r) {
            std::cout << "parse succeeded.";
        } else {
            std::cout << "parse failed.";
        }

        if (iter != end) {
            std::cout << " Remaining unparsed: " << std::quoted(std::string(iter, str.end()));
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
 --- "ab" --- parse failed. Remaining unparsed: "ab"
 --- " ab " --- parse failed. Remaining unparsed: " ab "
 --- " a b " --- parse succeeded.
 --- "a b happy trees are trailing" --- parse failed. Remaining unparsed: "a b happy trees are trailing"
```

Comment: Phew, you give out a lot to chew ;) Thanks for the detailed answer, as well as the information on more general topics. 
Considering your first point: But this only works when you are not using something like `+digit >> +digit`, doesn't it? Because in this case, there is no way in figuring out which digit belongs where. Using a skip parser for spaces, `123 456` is the same as `123456`, the same as `12 3456` etc (if i understand correctly).

Comment: Considering your solution: What is `qi::copy` for? I haven't seen it before and a quick looking-through-the-documentation brought nothing up.

Comment: @pschulz See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53033501/boost-spirit-qi-crashes-for-memory-violation/53035940#53035940 and the many links in it :)

Comment: Bonus points: 1. You are right, i will change that. 2. Yep, only a test case, since the parser is currently far from working well ;) 3. Will do :)

Comment: Btw: what god granted you this unlimited spirit knowledge? Do you belong to the development team?

Comment: Thanks for the link, so if i'm not using `auto`, i don't need `qi::copy`?

Comment: Upvoted for my agreement. I just like Qi and and happen to focus on Boost questions on StackOverflow. This brings a lot of accidental experience.

Comment: I just noticed I missed the question in your first comment. Yes, you understand correctly. Indeed `+digit >> +digit` is different because `+digit` is not a lexeme, whereas `qi::uint_` is - implicitly. The following would be fine: `lexeme[+digit] >> lexeme[+digit]` - making sure that no spaces are skipped inside the lexemes.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, this helped me a lot. You are using an explicit skip and lexeme, but if i use rules that accept a skipper with subrules that do *not* accept a skipper, the result should be the same, shouldn't it? At least my test cases work as expected. Are there any pitfalls to this approach?

Comment: Yes. Skippers are skippers, regardless of who specifies them. This **also** means that a rule is a lexeme if it is declared without a skipper (even if the surrounding grammar uses a skipper).